# What is the difference between JAX-WS and JAXB: JAX-WS: Java API for XML Web Service JAXB: Java Architecture for XML Binding

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

Both of them can be used to implement a soap-client. What're the differences?

Answer (score 16):

JAXB is an API used by JAX-WS, but it is independent of web services - it can be used in other contexts just as well.